# Calling a parent's parent's method, which has been overridden by the parent

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

How do you call a method more than one class up the inheritance chain if it's been overridden by another class along the way?

```
class Grandfather(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_thing(self):
        # stuff

class Father(Grandfather):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Father, self).__init__()

    def do_thing(self):
        # stuff different than Grandfather stuff

class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Son, self).__init__()

    def do_thing(self):
        # how to be like Grandfather?

        # How to call Grandfather's do_thing() here?
```

Answer (score 55):

If you always want `Grandfather#do_thing`, regardless of whether `Grandfather` is `Father`'s immediate superclass then you can explicitly invoke `Grandfather#do_thing` on the `Son` `self` object:

```
class Son(Father):
    # ... snip ...
    def do_thing(self):
        Grandfather.do_thing(self)
```

On the other hand, if you want to invoke the `do_thing` method of `Father`'s superclass, regardless of whether it is `Grandfather` you should use `super` (as in Thierry's answer):

```
class Son(Father):
    # ... snip ...
    def do_thing(self):
        super(Father, self).do_thing()
```

Answer (score 35):

You can do this using:

```
class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Son, self).__init__()

    def do_thing(self):
        super(Father, self).do_thing()
```

Comment: Following the comment of @Sean Vieira, in this case you will use the 'do_thing' method of the immediate Father's superclass what doesn't assure that it will be the 'Grandfather's method (in case of multi inherence)

Comment: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute