# Calling parent's parent's method, any consequences?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Basically, the problem I have is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18117974/1545579) and there are some answers, like below, where `Son` does some stuff like `Father` (the init in this case) and some other stuff like `GrandFather` (`do_thing`).

```
class GrandFather(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_thing(self):
        # stuff

class Father(GrandFather):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Father, self).__init__()

    def do_thing(self):
        # stuff different than Grandfather stuff

class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Son, self).__init__()

    def do_thing(self):
        super(Father, self).do_thing()  # <-- this line bypasses Father's implementation
```

What I am wondering is if there are any consequences to calling `super` like that (the last line above), i.e., passing a class type other than your own.
I mean something like your code breaking at some weird point where you don't expect it.

Comment: What is not already covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033903/python-super-method-and-calling-alternatives), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/what-does-super-do-in-python) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)?

Comment: @StephenRauch what is not covered? My question is not covered! :D Notice that the last line in my example reads `super(Father, self)` rather than `super(Son, self)`. The latter is the normal way to use `super` and this is covered in the links you provided. My question is however about the former, where I bypass the direct parent class, and call the method in the grandparent class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking about will generally work, but it may not do exactly what you intend in the presence of multiple inheritance. For instance, if `Son` also inherited from a `Mother` class (which due to incest was also a subclass of `Grandfather`), you'd not get the call you expected from your last line:

```
class GrandFather(object):
    def do_thing(self):
        print("Grandfather")

class Father(GrandFather):
    def do_thing(self):
        print("Father")

class Mother(GrandFather):
    def do_thing(self):
        print("Mother")

class Son(Father, Mother):
    def do_thing(self):
        super(Father, self).do_thing() # will print "Mother", not "Grandfather"
```

This issue could even crop up unexpectedly if the multiple inheritance was added in a `Son` subclass (e.g. `class GrandSon(Son, Mother): pass` with your previous definition of `Son` only inheriting from `Father`).

This may or may not be what you want. If you want to get `GrandFather`'s implementation of `do_thing` all the time, you should explicitly call `GrandFather.do_thing(self)`, rather than trying to use `super`.

But it's not generally a good idea to have classes bypassing their parents methods. You will probably be better served by reorganizing your code so it is not needed. Perhaps you could factor out the parts of `GrandFather.do_thing` that you want `Son` to be able to use into a separate method. You wouldn't need to override that method in `Father`, you could just not call it from `Father.do_thing`.