# Python inheritance - how to call grandparent method?

Tags: python

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class A:
  def foo(self):
    return "A"

class B(A):
  def foo(self):
    return "B"

class C(B):
  def foo(self):
    tmp = ... # call A's foo and store the result to tmp
    return "C"+tmp
```

What shall be written instead of `...` so that the grandparent method `foo` in class `A` is called? I tried `super().foo()`, but it just calls parent method `foo` in class `B`.

I am using Python 3.

Comment: This is the exact same case with this question asked 3 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937114/python-pattern-for-defaulting-to-a-grandparent-classs-implementation

Comment: Wanting to do this seems like a clear sign that your inheritance is wrong.  I strongly suggest fixing the code so that you don't need to skip over a parent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a parent's parent's method, which has been overridden by the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117974/calling-a-parents-parents-method-which-has-been-overridden-by-the-parent)

Comment: Even though this question happens to have good answers, the second has good answers as well. But this was asked 4 years later. So should be closed according to these guidelines: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-does-duplicate-closing-work-when-is-a-question-a-duplicate-and-how-should

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There are two ways to go around this:

Either you can use `A.foo(self)` method explicitly as the others have suggested - use this when you want to call the method of the `A` class with disregard as to whether `A` is `B`'s parent class or not:

```
class C(B):
  def foo(self):
    tmp = A.foo(self) # call A's foo and store the result to tmp
    return "C"+tmp
```

Or, if you want to use the `.foo()` method of `B`'s parent class regardless of whether the parent class is `A` or not, then use:

```
class C(B):
  def foo(self):
    tmp = super(B, self).foo() # call B's father's foo and store the result to tmp
    return "C"+tmp
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply be explicit about the class. `super()` allows you to be implicit about the parent, automatically resolving [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), but there's nothing else that's special about it.

```
class C(B):
    def foo(self):
       tmp = A.foo(self)
       return "C"+tmp
```

Comment: "Method Resolution Order" (MRO)

Comment: Thanks Tobias, fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

[Calling a parent's parent's method, which has been overridden by the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117974/calling-a-parents-parents-method-which-has-been-overridden-by-the-parent)
There is an explanation in this discuss already on how to go back in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicity call the method from the grandparent class:

```
class C(B):
    def foo(self):
       tmp = A.foo()
       return "C" + tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @UnholySheep. Please see the updated answer.